# php | Convert array to FIND_IN_SET

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, find-in-set

I'm trying to convert my array to query string. May be you can help me.

My array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

And I'm trying to convert this into:

```
(FIND_IN_SET('13', vals) || FIND_IN_SET('7', vals) || FIND_IN_SET('1', vals)) AND (FIND_IN_SET('14', vals) || FIND_IN_SET('2', vals))
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: How are you trying to build this query? What API are you using?

Comment: ^ Besides that; Have you tried something to get to your goal yourself?

Comment: What I have tried didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you.

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
 <?php

 $array = array(array(7,13,1),array(14,2));

 function convert_to_string($array)
 {
  return implode(" AND ",array_map(function($v){ return "(".implode(" || ", array_map( function($q){ return sprintf("FIND_IN_SET('%s', vals)",$q);},array_values($v))).")";},array_values($array)));    
 }

 echo convert_to_string($array);

 ?>
```

**Output**

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
 (FIND_IN_SET('7', vals) || FIND_IN_SET('13', vals) || FIND_IN_SET('1', vals)) AND (FIND_IN_SET('14', vals) || FIND_IN_SET('2', vals))
```

Comment: Bear in mind that if any of the values in the array are user-supplied, then this is ripe for SQL injection.